# Azure DevOps Repos synchronization between Organization

Tags: azure-devops, azure-repos

We have two Azure DevOps Organizations,
1. Development
2. Client

I would like to know if we can synchronize Azure DevOps Repos from one organization (Development) to different organization (Client) in a secure way?
If it is possible, what would be the best way to sync from one organization to another securely?

**NOTE:** We are able to manually clone the Repo from one to another organization for the first time with the help of PAT and GIT Auth but the problem arises when we want to update or re-sync the code. We have to manually re-import the repo (By deleting the existing one) to make changes.

We need to do this programmatically and to another organization.

Answer (score 7):

> Azure DevOps Repos synchronization between Organization

Sorry but as I know there's no such out-of-box feature available in Azure Devops Service.

There're similar user voices here: [Sync between projects in same org](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/905733/azure-repo-sync-in-multiple-projects-in-the-same-o.html) and [Automatically Sync Azure Devops Repos with GitHub Repos](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/516057/automatically-sync-azure-devops-repository-with-gi.html). Usually one organization is responsible for one product, so Azure Devops doesn't recommend cross-organization actions. But if you do want this behavior in your scenario, you can use these two directions:

1.Try free [Git Tools for Azure Devops](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nkdagility.gittasks&ssr=false#overview) extension from **Martin Hinshelwood**. Some steps about how to use it:

1. Install it in your `Development` organization, it contains one `Publish Git Repo` task.
2. Create a new classic build pipeline named `SyncRepos`, add the `Publish Git Repo` task in it.

   (Yaml pipeline also works well, but since this is one pipeline in which only exists one task, classic pipeline is enough)
3. Configure the task. We only need to configure the git repo url, so it's quite easy.

   [image]

   Assuming the name of same repos in another organization `Client` is `ReposToSync`, and this repos is in ProjectA. So the url you should enter in pipeline(in organization `Development`) should be:

   See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page#use-your-personal-access-token): `https://anything:PAT@dev.azure.com/Client/ProjectA/_git/ReposToSync`.

   (You should use a [PAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page#create-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate-access) which has repos-related permissions. I used `Full Access` one to test it easily but it should be **much better** if you create a PAT scoped in repos permissions. It's more **secure** !)
4. Now set the [trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?view=azure-devops), enable the CI and add all the branches into filter.

   [image]

   Yaml pipeline is better in step4 cause it supports trigger all branches with wildcard `*`. See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#branches).
5. Now in `Development` organization, when I have any change in `master` and `qwe` branches, it will **automatically** trigger the pipeline to run. Then the task will sync the changes in `Development`'s repos with repos in 'Client' organization.

   Any change in `Development` org will start a sync, if you want to same behavior in 'Client', you also need another similar pipeline in 'Client'. And, yaml pipeline with wildcard is better if you want the pipeline to monitor newly created branch.

**In additions:** Apart from using the task from extension, we can also use git commands in CMD task if you're familiar with those commands.

2.Feel free to post a new feature request to our [User Voice forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html). If you gets enough votes, the request's priority increases and the team would consider it seriously.

Hope all above helps :)

**Update1:**

No matter git commands or extension, if we want to make it more secure(**avoid** using PAT or other secrets directly in task), we can use secrets to store the important info like PAT.

1.See [create secret variable in Variable Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#create-a-variable-group), then [link the variable group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#use-a-variable-group), after that we can use $(MyPat) in task and it won't be displayed in log.

2.Also you can consider using [Azure Key Valut](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/key-vault/). Related doc: [Link secrets from an Azure key vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#link-secrets-from-an-azure-key-vault).

Comment: Thanks Lance, we have also tested using git commands and using ssh key pairs but that was also not suggested by the security team. We are using yaml pipelines only. Using Extension which was developed by Community, is it secure to do in this way ?

Comment: Since this is not extension from Microsoft, I can't guarantee that this is one secure way :( I'll add some edit to answer for some secure suggestions later.

Comment: @praveenkrish Hi friend, is there any update for it? Feel free to let me know if you need any further assistance in original issue :)

Comment: Thanks Lance for your suggestion, we will test and implement it

Comment: Great! Feel free to let me know if you need any further assistance about the original issue.

Answer (score 1):

Today I tried a way of doing it I found in a blog post and it worked perfectly (and is tremendously easy to do).

Steps:

1. Create a PAT *(personal access token)* to your Development organization (I see you already have one so skip this step)
2. Go to the target repo in the *Development* organization, click *clone* and copy the url
3. In the *Client* organization import the repository with the url you have copied and with your PAT (same here, I think you already did this so skip this step)
4. Now clone the repo to your computer from the *Client* organization and add a remote to the repo in your *Development* organization. If you don't know about remotes, this page could help: [Managing remote repositories](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/managing-remote-repositories)

After this, you will be able to push and fetch from the *Development* organization's repo.

Source: [Azure DevOps Fork Repos between two Organization - Michael Ghebremedin](http://michaelghebremedin.blogspot.com/2021/05/azure-devops-fork-repos-between-two.html)

Comment: This doesn't explain how to implement ongoing changes, i.e. when someone pushes to the Development repo, how do you get that across to the Client repo without deleting and recreating it?