# Connect Azure DevOps repository to another Azure DevOps repository from different account

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration, continuous-delivery

I have an organizational Microsoft account and a Visual Studio Professional subscription. Also I have my own Microsoft account and a project in Azure DevOps.
What I need is to connect my own DevOps repository to the DevOps project in my organizational account.

The goal is to setup CI/CD and deploy my project in Azure under my Visual Studio Professional subscription. I found OAuth configurations settings under Organization Settings in DevOps but there is no options to connect another DevOps repository.
The workflow:

1. Push changes to my own DevOps repo
2. Get this changes in organizational DevOps repo
3. Deploy to Azure under organizational Visual Studio Professional Subscription.

If there is some way to omit the 2nd step it would be great.

UPDATE:
steps done so far:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/build/connect - indicates there should be some way to achieve this goal, but I found nothing in google
2. Tried to use DevOps starter in Azure, but there is only one DevOps organization - the one from my organizational account and no way to add an external one.
3. Azure DevOps -> Organization Settings -> OAuth configurations: there are only GitHub and BitBucket source types.

Comment: What have you tried? What research have you done? What hasn't worked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consider these two directions:

**Import the own repo into your organizational devops project and develop code directly in the newly imported repo:**

[image]

**Or if you have specific reason to develop in own repo and then share the changes to organizational DevOps repo, then you need a synchronization between these two repos:**

1.You can follow [Azure DevOps Repos synchronization between Organization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61316005/azure-devops-repos-synchronization-between-organization/61335270#61335270) to make cross-organization synchronization between your two repos.

Assuming your own repo is `RepoA`, and the copy of `RepoA` in organizational Microsoft account is `RepoACopy`.
Follow the steps shared in link above, after that `RepoACopy` will get the changes when something changes in `RepoA`.

2.Create a pipeline for `RepoACopy` to deploy to Azure under organizational Visual Studio Professional Subscription. And set the CI/CD trigger for this pipeline.

Then every time you have changes in own RepoA => RepoACopy get changes => CI/CD pipeline will start to deploy the changes to Azure. It should meet your expected workflow.