# Azure DevOps pipeline usage between/across Organizations

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-pipelines

I am working on a task (a spike) which is about investigating the usage of pipeline (exists in) organization-1 to another organization-2.

So far I have found nothing on the Microsoft documentation about the usage of pipelines/projects/repos across organizations

Only information I have found in MS documentation ([Project QnA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/projects/about-projects?view=azure-devops#project-structure)) tells that you can move/transfer the data to another organization but not without loosing it or use the trid-party tool to copy the data.

Somewhat same information I found in this SO link ([Azure DevOps Repos synchronization between Organization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61316005/azure-devops-repos-synchronization-between-organization)).

I wonder if the above two solutions are the few possible ways to use the pipeline across organizations? And does Microsoft provide any "out-of-the-box" solution for it at all?

Does anyone else tried/faced the same scenario? If so, how you resolved this? Or did you contact the Azure support for this?

***Note*:** I also created two different organizations in DevOps and explored the ways (especially using service connections) if a pipeline or project becomes available in another organization, but, I could not found any solution for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Pipeline, if you want to use Azure Repos Git repositories in a different organization than your pipeline, you need to create [Azure Repos/Team Foundation Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#sep-tfsts) service connection, and use a `repository resource` in your pipeline:

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: MyAzureReposGitRepository # In a different organization
    endpoint: MyAzureReposGitServiceConnection
    type: git
    name: OtherProject/MyAzureReposGitRepo

trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- checkout: MyAzureReposGitRepository

- script: dir $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
```

More details, check the documentation here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops#repository-resource-definition

Comment: Is my reply helpful?

Comment: Hi Dong, Thank you for your reply. In my case it turned that we are creating an extension while running a pipeline which can be use across organizations. But I will still give a try to your answer and will let you know if it is working or not.

Comment: One question though, what name: OtherProject/MyAzureReposGitRepo represent. I mean with what values shall I replace them? I mean with the values of project and repo from ORG1 or from ORG2?

Comment: They are should be from ORG2.

Comment: I am able to clone the code from repo in other organization. But, I couldn't trigger the pipeline when there is a change in the repo from other organization within azure. Any suggestions to address this ? Thanks.