# Synapse Studio workspace replication and sync

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, azure-synapse

For my project, I need to have two identical Synapse Studio workspaces (one for internal dev and another for external client) in two different subscriptions and organizations. The goals are:

1. Replicate our internal Synapse Studio workspace for my client on their end
2. Sync my future updates in my workspace with client's workspace.

I'm trying to do this through Azure DevOps' CI/CD pipelines. Both my workspace and client's workspace are attached to a repo. I'm trying to trigger a push to the client's repo when there is a push on our end. However, it's not clear to me on how to trigger a git push with external organization, it seems like the repos sync can only happen between repos under same subscription. Can anyone give me some tips or refer me to a guide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Unfortunately, there is no option available in Azure to replicate the
> Azure Synapse workspace to another Workspace in same or different
> resource group or subscription.

You can raise a feature request [here](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/post/).

Also, there is no direct feature available in Azure DevOps to sync two repos.

As a out-of-box approach by using third party tool you can accomplish the task.

Try this third-party tool for [Git Tools for Azure DevOps](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nkdagility.gittasks&ssr=false#overview) from **Martin Hinshelwood** to Git Sync Management.

You can refer the answer on this [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61316005/azure-devops-repos-synchronization-between-organization) to follow the steps for the same.